# Is there a way to validate a device token with Apple Push Notification Service?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I am trying to set up Amazon SNS to send push notifications. After attempting to send a message to a device, Amazon SNS reports that the device token is not valid. However, I don't understand how that can be. Is there a way to validate a device token directly with APNS to know if this is truly the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon SNS is able to provide a unified API for various push services including APNS.  Different push providers have different ways of indicating that a push token is no longer valid.  As part of providing a unified interface push tokens are indicated to no longer be active when they are used.